# XML design for parsing in C#

Tags: c#, comparative-review, xml, configuration, asp.net-core

I am trying to design XML with configuration info so I can parse it into this code:

```
...
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password settings
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;
});
...
```

I have already 4 versions of the XML code, but I don't know which one to choose:

```
<identity>
    <!-- version 1 -->
    <password>
        <RequireDigit>true</RequireDigit>
        <RequiredLength>8</RequiredLength>
        <RequireNonAlphanumeric>false</RequireNonAlphanumeric>
        <RequireUppercase>true</RequireUppercase>
        <RequireLowercase>false</RequireLowercase>
        <RequiredUniqueChars>6</RequiredUniqueChars>
    </password>
    <!-- version 2 -->
    <password   RequireDigit="true" 
                RequiredLength="8" 
                RequireNonAlphanumeric="false" 
                RequireUppercase="true" 
                RequireLowercase="false" 
                RequiredUniqueChars="6"
    />
    <!-- version 3 -->
    <password>
        <RequireDigit value="true"/>
        <RequiredLength value="8"/>
        <RequireNonAlphanumeric value="false"/>
        <RequireUppercase value="true"/>
        <RequireLowercase value="false"/>
        <RequiredUniqueChars value="6"/>
    </password>
    <!-- version 4 -->
    <password>
        <RequireDigit/>
        <RequiredLength value="8"/>
        <RequireUppercase/>
        <RequiredUniqueChars value="6"/>
    </password>
</identity>
```

- Are there any rules when to choose which one?
- Or how to decide which is the best or the most suitable?

Comment: Clarification needed. The code snippet looks like .net-core startup code. This would lead me to ask why XML and not JSON? Next I am uncertain what you want reviews here?

Comment: Yes, it is .net-core startup file. I want to use XML because except of information for the startup file, the XML file contains also other data (I provided just part of the whole file). So I want to know other's opinion on which version of XML data format is the best / is used.

Comment: You don't know this yet but you want `JSON`.

Comment: And why would I want JSON?

Comment: It's easier to read, easier to maintain, lighter, it's natively supported by asp.net-core, and there is only one way for storing your configuration so your question would answer itself with json.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to recreate functionality that is already provided out of the box.

Reference [Configure an ASP.NET Core App](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration)

From documentation it supports providers for INI, JSON, and XML.

> Each configuration value maps to a string key. There's built-in binding support to deserialize settings into a custom POCO object (a simple .NET class with properties).

Reference [ASP.NET Core 1.0 Configuration Deep Dive](https://joonasw.net/view/asp-net-core-1-configuration-deep-dive)

For XML, you need to add this NuGet package: *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml* and the format that provider uses would look like this for your settings

**Note**: *It matches closely to version 1 in your example*

```
<configuration>
    <identityOptions>
        <password>
            <RequireDigit>true</RequireDigit>
            <RequiredLength>8</RequiredLength>
            <RequireNonAlphanumeric>false</RequireNonAlphanumeric>
            <RequireUppercase>true</RequireUppercase>
            <RequireLowercase>false</RequireLowercase>
            <RequiredUniqueChars>6</RequiredUniqueChars>
        </password>
    </identity>
</configuration>
```

And the following would be added as part of configuration

```
//...
.AddXmlFile("appsettings.xml", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
//...
```

If using JSON then

```
{  
  "IdentityOptions": {
    "Password": {
      "RequireDigit": true
      "RequiredLength": 8
      "RequireNonAlphanumeric": false
      "RequireUppercase": true
      "RequireLowercase": false
      "RequiredUniqueChars": 6
    }
  }
}
```

And the following would be added as part of configuration

```
//...
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
//...
```

You appear to already be setting up `IOptions`, which is good.

```
//...
// Register the ConfigurationBuilder instance which IdentityOptions binds against.
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(Configuration);

//...
```

This will allow constructor dependency injection with `IOptions<TOptions>` to access settings

```
private readonly IdentityOptions options;

public MyClass(IOptions<IdentityOptions> identity) {
    options = identity.Value;
}
```